# comparision of files using packed decimal fields

Tags: mainframe

Hi I have 2 files and I want to compare them using the key field and a packed decimal field in the file.

I have searched in many forums but I could not get the solution.

Please provide me a solution either in the syncsort or DFsort.

File has LRECL of 200 and the field value is starting at 84 and the length is 9.

Both files have same format I need the ouput as below.

Key is starting from 1 and the lenght is 22 and type is alphanumeric for both the files.

File1:should have the matched records from file1 and file2
File2:should have the unmatched records from file1 and file2

Thanks in Advance,
Lakshmi

Comment: Welcome to SO. Usually, it is expected from the question's author to show some effort on achieving the goal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a very simple JOINKEYS. You'll need a JOIN UNPAIRED. You'll need two OUTFIL statements for your two output files.

It is unusual to have a choice of either DFSORT or SyncSort. DFSORT has a "matching marker" for JOINKEYS, so very easy to do the final extract. SyncSort relies on you testing for a value which cannot exist in the data to show that a record from one file or the other is not present. Find out which one you have (ICE messages in the sysout from the step are from DFSORT, WER messages are from SyncSort).

I can't believe that you won't be able to find many examples of JOINKEYS if you do a bit of googling.

If you get stuck, add what you have tried to your question, being clear about which SORT product you actually have access to.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the DFSORT [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=dfsort-zos-application-programming-guide), I believe you will find that using the [JOINKEYS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-using-joinkeys-application-joining-two-files) statement will your desired result.